# Git repository pushing another project (Bitbucket)

Tags: macos, git, terminal, repository

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/team/project-name.git
git push -u origin --all # pushes up the repo and its refs for the first time
git push -u origin --tags # pushes up any tags
```

Bitbucket asked me to run these lines of code (with my info filled in obviously) and when I did my terminal window was obviously uploading a project to Bitbucket, but whenever it finished and I cloned the repo to my local machine, the project was the source for homebrew (which isn't my project, and I didn't even know what it was until this error occurred).

I've already tried recreating the repo by deleting it (remotely) and creating it again. I've already tried recreating "master" and "origin". I've tried setting the url for origin, I've tried uploading a completely different project, I've tried moving the project folder to a new directory, and still all I've gotten was "homebrew".

Misc Info: Running Mac OSX 10.10.2 on Mac Book Pro. I've been able to upload this project successfully before, but now it's not working.

Comment: What is the output of `git config -l` after you `cd` into your repo?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to delete the .git file in the repo on your local repository.
 
So `cd` to your local repo, and run `rm -rf .git`. This is like the git version of "did you try turn it on and off again".

Good luck, I hope this helps